# Different image align ment for mobile

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I Have a two column content theme 
with one column as text and other as image 
i have coded it in such a way that (coded in html)

It looks like
Text - Img ,
Img - Text ,
Text - Img ,
Img - Text ,
Text - Img ,
Img - Text ,

But for mobile i need it in 
Text - Img,
Text - Img,
Text - Img,
Text - Img,
Text - Img
My column code

```
.one-half,
.three-sixths,
.two-fourths {
width: 48.4375%;
line-height: 1.2875;
 }
```

Html Code

```
  <div class="one-half first"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
```

Is their a Possibility for changing it in mobile only in html or css (if yes, then how?)

[My Site Url](http://d3sign.biz/)

Comment: I'm curious to know where the 1.2875 comes from. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.one-half-first
{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
.one-half
{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 200px)
{
.one-half-first
{
float:left;
width:100px;
position:relative;
left:20px;
}
.one-half
{
float:left;
width:100px;
position:relative;
left:100px;
}
.one-half img
{
width:50px;
height:auto;
}
.clear
{
clear:both;
}

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="one-half-first">ihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdscihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdscihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdsc</div>
  <div class="one-half"><img src="file:///C|/tribhuvan/s2 dump/DCIM/sms/2012-08-14 10.29.41-1.jpg" width="300" height="200" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="one-half"><img src="file:///C|/tribhuvan/s2 dump/DCIM/sms/2012-08-14 10.29.41-1.jpg" width="300" height="200" /></div>
<div class="one-half-first">ihbibdsc ihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdscihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdscihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdsc</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="one-half-first">ihbibdsc ihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdscihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdscihbdbgrbgbdfvv vfv sfviuhisdv ksbihv ijbsiv ibisfv ibisv
monjonsv kbniksfv kinsviknv nionsiov iknbibsv nklnosv ibdsc</div>
  <div class="one-half"><img src="file:///C|/tribhuvan/s2 dump/DCIM/sms/2012-08-14 10.29.41-1.jpg" width="300" height="200" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

try this bro this shud help u any other practical problems or code doest wrk with ur code plz let me know i have cople of other ways to solve the problem as u like.

Comment: No the problem is if we code like what i have or what u wrote one image will below the text and other will be above the text in mobile what i need is in mobile always the code need to be below the text but not on the desktop screen where it should appear as it is

Comment: i dnt get u plz elobrate what u want to say

Comment: No the problem is if we code like what i have or what u wrote one image will below the text and other will be above the text in mobile what i need is in mobile always the code need to be below the text but not on the desktop screen where it should appear as it is